I tried using a slope handling movement script from a tutorial video, my player character falls through any objects with the ground layer
I set the layer of various slopes in my environment to Ground and then set the layer that the slope detector is meant to detect to Ground as well. This would then activate a separate movement setting for moving on slopes. However, this instead just causes me to fall through the slope and I am unsure why this is the case.
I tried out the script from the tutorial video Rigidbody FPS Controller Tutorial #3 | Slope Handling + FIXES! for giving my player character the ability to walk on slopes.
What I expected was for my character to be able to walk up and down the slope. Instead my character fell through the slope.
The code I was using is shown below.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    float playerHeight = 2f;

    [SerializeField] Transform orientation;

    [Header("Movement")]
    public float moveSpeed = 6f;
    public float movementMultiplier = 10f;
    [SerializeField] float airMultiplier = 0.4f;


    [Header("Keybinds")]
    [SerializeField] KeyCode jumpKey = KeyCode.Space;

    [Header("Jumping")]
    public float jumpForce = 5f;

    [Header("Drag")]
    float groundDrag = 6f;
    float airDrag = 2f;

    float rbDrag = 6f;

    float horizontalMovement;
    float verticalMovement;

    [Header("Ground Detection")]
    [SerializeField] LayerMask groundMask;
    bool isGrounded;
    float groundDistance = 0.4f;
     

    Vector3 moveDirection;
    Vector3 slopeMoveDirection;

    Rigidbody rb;

    RaycastHit slopeHit;
    private bool OnSlope()
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out slopeHit, playerHeight /2 + 0.5f))
        {
            if (slopeHit.normal != Vector3.up)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.freezeRotation = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position - new Vector3(0, 1, 0), groundDistance, groundMask);

        MyInput();
        ControlDrag();

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(jumpKey) && isGrounded)
        {
            Jump();
        }

        slopeMoveDirection = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(moveDirection, slopeHit.normal);
    }

    void MyInput()
    {
        horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        verticalMovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalMovement + orientation.right * horizontalMovement;
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    void ControlDrag()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            rb.drag = groundDrag;
        }
        else
        {
            rb.drag = airDrag;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();
    }

    void MovePlayer()
    {
        if (isGrounded && !OnSlope())
        {
            rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * movementMultiplier, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
        else if (isGrounded && OnSlope())
        {
            rb.AddForce(slopeMoveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * movementMultiplier, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
        else if (!isGrounded)
        {
            rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * movementMultiplier * airMultiplier, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

    }
}



Ok um, I moved my environment objects into an empty game object and had the game object set to default with the environment objects set to Ground and now it works???
IDK how that solved the issue but maybe some of you can explain it in case anyone else sees this post.

Maybe you had modified something in the Layer Collision Matrix (it's part of the Physics Settings) that made the two objects to ignore each others layers?
